# What would this song section be called?

Tags: theory, lyrics

I'm new to genius transcribing and I'm unsure of the song sections. In the image below  I don't know what these parts with the red dots are called. Above first red dot is verse 1 and nothing else.

[image: transcribe]

The song is:

Comment: Which song are the lyrics from? A Google search of the first line visible of your lyrics, "Lactose intolerance selling cheese for necessities", returned nothing.

Comment: @Dekkadeci That's because it hasn't been transcribed. I am new to genius.com and fixing up songs with missing lyrics. I don't have enough points to post on the forum. I just need to know what to put in brackets next to the red dots as i'm unsure the proper part. The first one I think is a prechorus and the 2nd one i am unsure

Comment: Is there such a thing as a prechorus that doesn't directly lead to a chorus, though? Also, again, which song are the lyrics from? We'd be able to understand the song's structure better if we can listen to the song.

Comment: I have no idea that's why i'm here

Comment: song is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmaqWo28myc

Answer (score 1):

By listening to the song you provided that would be the chorus. The second time around it is repeated twice (up until the "to turn in, to turn in") and the rest of the lyrics would be something between the continuation of the chorus in an outro way. You might call it just *outro*, if you want to be more specific.

Comment: without listening I'd give the same answer ...